# pymongo groupby to return the top 2 documents grouped on a key

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, nosql-aggregation

Sample collection:

```
#0
{ '_id' : ObjectId("5291c70419181fe0f8ea9ff8"),
'state' : 'CA',
'hitCount' : 100
}

#1
{ '_id' : ObjectId("5d3443fdf4441fe0f8ea9kk2"),
'state' : 'CA',
'hitCount' : 10
}

#2
{ '_id' : ObjectId("52943242344fe0f8ea9ff348"),
'state' : 'CA',
'hitCount' : 1
}

#3
{ '_id' : ObjectId("5291c7er89482942342344a"),
'state' : 'NY',
'hitCount' : 100
}

#4
{ '_id' : ObjectId("342834723942sdfsafa334"),
'state' : 'NY',
'hitCount' : 10
}

#5
{ '_id' : ObjectId("ewr8943459n0ads1231411"),
'state' : 'NY',
'hitCount' : 1
}
```

How would I return documents 0,1,3 & 4 -- grouped by state and returning the top 2 hitCount's.

I have been trying to use the aggregate group function. I think I'm getting close but my solution still uses a lot of client side work - I bring in all the documents and then get the ones I need. This definitely wont scale so need some help to fix it.

I'm using pymongo.

Comment: Please add what you've tried so we can help.

Comment: there is no way to do it at the moment with aggregation framework.  Vote up https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9377 to make it easy.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I'm actually using Talend to run a processes to do this. That process takes a while but I'm atleast able to pretty much anything I want.